# Add/Delete a record in Access using Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Need help with my assignment. I would like to add and delete a record for a selected customer. I can add a new record to the selected customer but when I delete the order it deletes the customer too. I believe it could be the RefreshRecordset call but if I only call orders then I will get everyone's record and not just the selected customer. I'm pretty much stuck on what's wrong with this code.

[image]

```
Private RecCount As Integer
Private CurrentOrderNo As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    EnableButtons
    CreateDbObjects
    With Sheets("Data").cboCustomer
        CurrentOrderNo = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
    End With
    RefreshRecordset CurrentOrderNo
End Sub


Private Sub RefreshRecordset(ByVal ThisCusNo As Integer)
    ' This routine opens the recordset and selects the
    ' desired record (based on ThisCusNo)

   On Error GoTo error_handle:
    sql = "Select * From Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.CusNo = Customers.CusNo WHERE Orders.CusNo = " & ThisCusNo
     rs.Open sql
    If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then  'No customer records, so go into 'Add' mode
        RecCount = 0
        cmdAdd_Click
    Else
        rs.MoveLast ' <<--This is done to ensure a correct RecordCount in the next line
        RecCount = rs.RecordCount
        rs.MoveFirst
        rs.Find "CusNo = " & ThisCusNo
        UpdateTextBoxes
    End If
    Exit Sub
error_handle:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 91
        CreateDbObjects
        Resume
    Case 3705
        rs.Close
        Resume
     Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
     End Select
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateTextBoxes()
    ' This routine is used to place values for the current record into the userform text boxes
    If RecCount = 0 Then
        Me.Caption = "Order Maintenance - Record 0 of 0"
    Else
        Me.Caption = "Order Maintenance - Record " & _
           rs.AbsolutePosition & " of " & RecCount
        lblCustomer = rs.Fields("LName") & ", " & rs.Fields("FName")
        txtDate = rs("PurchDate").Value
        txtProduct = rs("Product").Value
        txtUnits = rs("Units").Value
        txtAmount = rs("Amount").Value
        lblOrderNo = rs("CusNo").Value
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Me.Caption = "Order Maintenance - Add new record..."
    Me.Tag = "Add"  ' Indicates that we're in 'Add' mode
    AddChangeClick
End Sub

Private Sub cmdChange_Click()
    Me.Caption = "Order Maintenance - Change current record..."
    Me.Tag = "Change"  ' Indicates that we're in 'Change' mode
    AddChangeClick
End Sub


Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    ' Note: The user can click OK to exit Add/Change mode OR to dismiss the user form
    If Me.Tag = "Add" Or Me.Tag = "Change" Then ' User clicked OK while in Add/Change mode
        If DataMissing() = True Then
            msg = "Required data is missing." & vbCrLf & "Please Try again."
            MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        AddOrChangeRecord
        Me.Tag = vbOK   ' Takes us out of Add/Change mode
        EnableButtons
    Else ' User clicked OK while not in Add/Chnage mode
        Me.Hide
    End If

End Sub

Private Function DataMissing() As Boolean
    ' This routine just checks to see if any TextBoxes are empty
    DataMissing = False
    For Each ctl In Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
            If ctl.Text = "" Then DataMissing = True: Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Sub AddOrChangeRecord()
    Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset

    If Me.Tag = "Add" Then
        ' If we're Adding a record we need a new (unused) value for OrderNo
        sql = "Select Max(OrderNo) From Orders"
        rs2.Open sql, db, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        rs.AddNew
        rs("CusNo").Value = CurrentCusNo
    End If

    rs("PurchDate").Value = CStr(txtDate)
    rs("Product").Value = CStr(txtProduct)
    rs("Units").Value = CStr(txtUnits)
    rs("Amount").Value = CStr(txtAmount)
    rs("CusNo").Value = CStr(lblOrderNo)
    rs.Update

    RefreshRecordset CurrentCusNo
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim CurrentRecord As Integer

    ' First see if there are records in the Orders table for this customer
    ' If so, we don't want to delete the customer record
    CusIdNo = rs("CusNo").Value
    sql = "Select Count(*) As RecordsLeft From Orders Where CusNo = " & CusIdNo
    rs2.Open sql, db, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    If rs2.Fields("RecordsLeft") < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Orders remain for this customer.", vbExclamation, "Cannot Delete..."
    Else
        msg = "Are you sure you want to delete this record?"
        If MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Warning...") = vbYes Then
            CurrentRecord = WorksheetFunction.Max(rs.AbsolutePosition - 1, 1)
            rs.Delete  ' AbsolutePosition is undefined after deleting a record!
            RecCount = RecCount - 1
            If RecCount = 0 Then
                Me.Tag = "Quit"
                cmdOK_Click
            Else
                rs.AbsolutePosition = CurrentRecord
                MsgBox "Record deleted.", vbInformation, "Confirmation"
                UpdateTextBoxes
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    ' Recall that cmdCancel is only visible in Add/Change mode
    If RecCount = 0 Then
        Me.Hide
    Else
        EnableButtons
        Me.Tag = vbCancel  ' We're no longer in Add/Change mode
        UpdateTextBoxes
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    ' This prevents the user from dismissing the form by clicking the close button
    Cancel = vbYes
    If Me.Tag = "Add" Or Me.Tag = "Change" Then
        cmdCancel_Click
    Else
        cmdOK_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are all the order numbers numeric?

Comment: Yes. all the OrderNo's are numeric.

Comment: looks like there are null references to `rs` inside of `UpdateTextBoxes`. Please put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, above all other code, and recompile.

Comment: Why use Excel for data entry? rs is declared and set in one procedure and referenced in others. How are you making recordset available to multiple procedures?

Comment: I'm using Excel because it's an assignment.